# Sending mail error in PHP on IIS

Tags: php, email, iis

I am using a small script of php to send email through my IIS based server.  When I try to send mail an error occurrs:

```
"The specified CGI application exceeded the allowed time for processing. The server has deleted the process."
```

Although simple php script is working fine, my sample code is given below.

```
<?php  
    if(mail('sheery_1@hotmail.com','test subject','test message')){
      echo('ok');
    } else{
      echo('not ok');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you configured smtp to send mails ?

Comment: which iis version are you working with

Comment: yes i have configured smtp and i am testing it on my live server, at home server scripts works fine but at my live website it gives that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure your home server as this feature is ready pre configured on hosting servers.

Try to change the php.ini and change the smtp paths etc

Comment: but i am testing it on my live server not home server, at home server it works fine but when i make it live it gives that error.